# how to tell subclipse to ignore modified file on commit

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have a file that is under version control and modified by me. However I do not want to commit it, I want that only I will have the specific change I made and everybody else will have the file in its original version.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I often have the same problem. My solution is to work with **change sets**. If you're working with Mylyn, every change will be added to the active task.
If you're not using Mylyn, you can create change sets manually in the synchronize view. Change the view to show **SVN Change Sets**. In that view you can every change add to change set. When you commit from now on only change sets, you have full control about what you commit.

[image]

That is only my solution for the same problem.

Comment: Where is the option as in the screenshot? Can't find it.

Comment: @JamesFu In the 'Team Synchronization' perspective in the 'Synchronize' view!

Comment: Thanks. Found it. But since I've got quite a lot of local files to exclude from committing, TortoiseSVN's flat view & management is still best solution to this case.