# Getting Subclipse to ignore changes

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Is there any way to tell Subclipse to ignore changes made to a particular file?

I have a config XML file that exists in SVN but that I need to tweak locally for my machine.  But thanks to that one file, the entire package is marked with the little `*` icon telling me I have changes in that project, which is a nuisance.  Is there a way to tell Subclipse some version of "Yeah, that file's supposed to be out-of-synch with the repository, don't worry about it"?

Comment: Read here: [Subclipse svn:ignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066809/subclipse-svnignore/1069412)

Comment: Maybe [how to tell subclipse to ignore modified file on commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4666034/2294031) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a file is versioned, it cannot be ignored.  What a lot of people do is use template files, such as file named foo.xml.in or foo.tmpl.  Then you version control that file and use some process to create the foo.xml file from the template.  The foo.xml file is then ignored so you can change it at will.